# is_numeric() returns false for unicode string number

Tags: php, unicode, xampp

I have installed xampp on an ubuntu machine. I found out that `is_numeric` function returns `FALSE` for unicode string numbers. for example for `۳۴۵۳` which is `3453` returns `FALSE` and also conversion to `int` evaluates all unicode number strings to `0`. It is less than a week that I migrated to linux family os. Before this it was working fine on my windows machine and everything was ok. What is the solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

First set Unicode number `۳۴۵۳` as integer by [`settype`](http://www.php.net/settype) and then validate with `is_numeric`.

**Edit 1**

The thing is first you need to convert to proper `UTF-8` and then you can validate as integer.

```
    if(!mb_check_encoding($content, 'UTF-8') 
        OR !($content === mb_convert_encoding(mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-32', 'UTF-8' ), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-32'))) { 

        $content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8'); 

        if (mb_check_encoding($content, 'UTF-8')) { 
            // log('Converted to UTF-8'); 
        } else { 
            // log('Could not converted to UTF-8'); 
        } 
    } 
    return $content; 
}
```

Taken from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)

Comment: If you use `settype` "integer" for this string, it will become 0, instead of ۳۴۵۳. So, this won't work.

Comment: @Noor If I use `settype()` then it converts ‍‍‍numbers like `۳‍۴۳۵‍` to `0`

Comment: Currently I have to use `preg_replace()` function to change the user input numbers if they are unicode characters